# Error Accessing Elements from Function in Large C Arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I have a strange error which I guess comes down (as usual) to something in memory management. Here is my code:

```
#define LX 4
#define LY 4

int n = LX * LY;
void matrixInit( double *h );

int main(void)
{
  int dim;
  dim = (int) pow( 2.0, (double) n );
  int k;
  double *h;
  h = (double *)malloc( dim * dim * sizeof(double) );

  for(k = 0; k < dim * dim; k++)
    {
      h[k] = 0.0;
    }
  printf("dimension is: %d\n", dim);
  matrixInit( h );

  free( h );
  return 0;
}


void matrixInit( double *h)
{
  h[15379] = 0.0;
}
```

I have an array of `double` that is `2^16` by `2^16`. I can assign values to it in the main function with no problem. Now I have created a function, `matrixInit`, to change values in the array. Accessing elements `0-15379` works fine, but for any element after that, I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Comment: Nitpick: replace `dim = (int) pow ...` with `dim = 1 << n`

Comment: You are trying to allocate 32Gb of space .... `(2^(4*4))^2*8/1024/1024/1024 = 32Gb`

Comment: You should check whether malloc() is successful.

Comment: Works fine here: http://ideone.com/1zzlpM The problem is something specific to your system.

Comment: Assuming `sizeof(double)` is 8, the amount of memory you are requesting is  `2^16 * 2^16 * 8 = 34359738368 = 32 GiB`. If your computer does not have that much memory, `malloc` probably fails.

Comment: To be fair, it didn't work for elements past 15379, and your test checked 15379 (instead of 15380 or higher), but I do think it is likely that the problem is system specific.

Comment: @RSahu Always good practice to check malloc, but I think it works here. Otherwise, the for loop above the `matrixInit` call would fail [immediately]

Comment: Yes, and it still prints the dimension before the segmentation fault.

Comment: That is a 2D array, so it should be `double (*h)[dim];` and use 2D indexing. And do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: Use `size_t` for such large arrays (or arrays in general; that is the correct type). An `int` likely too small to hold `2**32` - but that depends on your platform. Note that for an array that large, you need >32 bit indexes; make sure your platform supports that with `_Static_assert(SIZE_MAX >= whatever_your_think_your_array_might_use_at_maximum)`!

Comment: @Olaf, it is still only a 1D array, just of size 2^16*2^16. I do view it somewhat as 2D in that I refer to its elements as h[i + dim * j], where i and j range from 0 to 2^16-1, and dim = 2^16, but I keep it as 1D for simplicity.

Comment: @Olaf Are you referring to the variable "dim" with your `size_t` remark?

Comment: You may find `dim * dim` evaluating to `0` if you have 32-bit ints

Comment: @Olaf it *could* be that .. "should" is just your personal style preference . There's nothing wrong with OP's array style.

Comment: @M.M: For a 2D array, it actually "has to". But OP clarified in a comment to my answer, it actually is a 1D array with manual 2D indexing. That's perfectly fine, just no 2D array.

Comment: @Emilie: I'm fine with an 1D array, but stongly disagree about "simplicity". `h[r][c]` is imo more clear. Anyway, the actual issue is the types.

Comment: @M.M I do indeed get `0` from `dim * dim`. Thanks.

Comment: the first, and most likely, problem is the returned value from the call to `malloc()` was not checked (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: In C, when calling `malloc()` do not cast the returned value.  Its' type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: the posted code is trying to allocate 34 359 214 080 bytes.  (32gig).  If your RAM is not significantly larger than 32gig, the malloc will fail.    (Yet another reason to always check (!=NULL) the returned value from `malloc()`. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You fell into the trap of using inappropriate types. In general, the correct type to index an array is `size_t`. This type is explicititly the type to be valid for all indexes allowed on a platform.

For typical 32 and 64 bit platforms, an `int` is 32 bits wide. This allows for max. `2**31 - 1` (`**`= power of). This is apparently not sufficient for `2**16 * 2**16 == "**32` entries. Any overflow of a signed integer is undefined behaviour by the standard. Search for that term, you don't want it! Simply put: your are lost once it occurs - no further research necessary.

Said that, let's try get things right.

---

First is to make sure you can index arrays that large. This is very likely only possible on 64 bit platforms. To make sure, use

```
#include <stdint.h>

_Static_assert( (SIZE_MAX >= (uintmax_t)YOUR_MAX_DIM * YOUR_MAX_DIM), "Platform does not support arrays that large" )
```

If you do not have a standard compliant (i.e. C11) compiler, use `#ifdef`. `uintmax_t` is the largest possible unsigned integer type on your platform. As we assume at least C99 compliance, that would be at least 64 bits (the min. required width of an `unsigned long long`).

Then you have to make sure all calculations are processed as `size_t`. So:

```
#define LX ((size_t)4)
#define LY ((size_t)4)
```

That prevents standard integer conversions to generate trouble.

Then use correct types consistently:

```
size_t n = LX * LY;

int main(void)
{
    size_t dim;
    dim = (size_t)1 << n;  // don't use floating point for exact results!
```

and so on. Be very careful not to have a raw `int` slip in from a constant.

Another issue is: you want a 2D array, aka matrix. But you allocate a 1D array and have a pointer to the first entry. A pointer is not an array!

For a 2D array and a pointer to the first entry, you use:

```
double (*h)[dim];
```

this is a pointer to a 1D array. This 1D array is the 2nd dimension or a 2D array, so the pointer still points to the first entry of a 1D array; just that this entry is an array itself. Note that we have to specify the dimension of that "inner" array.

Then, in C you should not cast `void *`, which is returned by `malloc` & friends:

```
h = malloc( dim * sizeof(*h) );
```

I also used a simplicication, by just using the size of whatever `h` points to. Remember that is a 1D array. But that pattern is universal.

Then, alwas check the result of functions which might encounter an error relevant for program execution:

```
if ( h == NULL )
    exit(1);
```

This terminates the program gracefully if no array could be allocated - well possible for arrays that size.

The loop has to be split in an inner and outer loop over `dim`. Use correct types:

```
for ( size_t k = 0 ; k < dim ; k++)
    for ( size_t j = 0 ; ...
        h[k][j] = 0.0;
```

mind using normal 2D indexing and local definition of the index variables.

For output, you also need the correct type for a `size_t` argument:

```
printf("dimension is: %zu\n", dim);
```

And don`t forget to free allocated memory blocks:

```
free(h);
```

---

Finally the function signature has to be changed:

```
void matrixInit(size_t dim, double h[dim][dim]);
```

This works because an array-argument is always converted to a pointer to the first entry. Note this is true for the **first** index (`h` is not an array here anymore). This is identical with

```
void matrixInit(size_t dim, double (*h)[dim]);
```

(compare with the declaration of `h` in `main`!). But the array-notation is more clear about the dimensions.

The call has to pass the `dim`, of course, but the array still is passed as `h`.

Also note I passed the dimension of the array to the function. That is necessary, as

1. the pointer does not include any information about the size and
2. it is required by the compiler to calculate the size of the inner array.

It is in general good style to pass all required information to a function where appropriate. Otherwise you had to use a global variable which here is a clear no-go.

Comment: Thanks for this response! I will try fixing my types tomorrow. Just one comment: my array is in fact only 1D, rather than 2D. It represents a matrix, but I collapse it into 1D. Various matrix algebra libraries require this.

Comment: @Emilie: Yes, many people have problems with 2D arrays in C. Most use an array of pointers, but that is likely less good performing. I'll leave the part with the 2D arrays; might be useful for other readers, too. Take that about 64 bit platform seriously (`SIZE_MAX` will still ensure that). Even iff a 32 bit platform supports >4GiB applications, indexes are likely still limited). Please remember to accept and/or upvote once you are sure this is what you need. Took quite some time.

Comment: It was indeed a problem with type. When I printed `dim * dim` with the `int` type, it gave me zero, but `size_t` gives the correct integer. Good job on spotting it despite my misdirection thinking it was a memory management problem! My problem now is that `malloc` cannot allocate that much memory, but I will look into what I can do for this myself. The error is now at least explained.

Comment: @Emilie: As I wrote, anything can happen with _undefined behaviour_. Prepare to encounter nasal daemons, Glad I could help. As an alternative you can use an array of pointers. Each entry points to one row of the array. But - as you wrote - that will cause trouble with your libraries.

Comment: One proposed edit for future readers: the command I needed to use to check array indexing potential was `_Static_assert(SIZE_MAX >= (uintmax_t)YOUR_MAX_DIM * YOUR_MAX_DIM, "error message string" );`. I needed to add the error message argument for it to work.
[From here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Static_assert)

Comment: @Emilie: Thanks, edited. As I wrote, it was not meant to be that long; just grew while typing.